# Finding the Expectation - Continuous case

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

For the RV with PDF,

f(x;$\lambda$) = (e<sup>-x</sup>x<sup>$\lambda$</sup>)/$\lambda$!, x > 0

Find the Expectation.

I tried integration by parts, but it gets complicated. I got some answer like:

-(e<sup>-x</sup>x<sup>$\lambda+2$</sup>)/$\lambda$!(x-$\lambda$-1).

I am not sure if this is right. Could someone help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A standard trick is to note that $xf(x;\lambda)=\mathrm e^{-x}x^{\lambda+1}(\lambda!)^{-1}=(\lambda+1)f(x;\lambda+1)$ and that, since $f(\ ;\lambda+1)$ is a PDF, one has $\int\limits_0^\infty f(x;\lambda+1)\mathrm dx=1$.

Thus,
$E[X]=\int\limits_0^\infty xf(x;\lambda)\mathrm dx=\int\limits_0^\infty(\lambda+1)f(x;\lambda+1)\mathrm dx=\lambda+1$ with no computation at all.

*Exercise:*

Use the same trick to compute $E[X^2]$ with no pain. Deduce that $\mathrm{var}(X)=\lambda+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a computer algebra system to check your work? In this case, your density $f(x)$ is:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/parammixedPoisson.png))</sub>

and $E[X]$ can be found as:

```
 Expect[x, f]
```

> 1 + $\lambda$

where `Expect` is a function from the `mathStatica` add-on to *Mathematica* (I am an author of the former). I am sure you could do this with Maple or other packages too, and then use the package to check your own manual integration, if you need that.